# Call to undefined method stdClass::pluck() in laravel

Tags: laravel

the data is : `[{"key":1,"value":"album1"},{"key":2,"value":"album2"}]`

I'm trying to save into the database but I constantly get this error

`Call to undefined method stdClass::pluck()`

controller

```
$music->album_id = json_decode($request->album)->pluck('key');;
$music->save();
```

Comment: `pluck` is a Collection method and you don't have a collection there you have an plain object

Comment: so what is the appropriate method?

Comment: StdClass objects don't have methods. If the object has a key property, you should be able to refer to it directly with `->key`.

Comment: You can wrap the data in `collect()` to turn it into a collection, if you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using an object you can access the key directly, like

```
$album = json_decode($request->album);
$music->album_id = $album->key;
$music->save();
```